# Easy linear matrix inequality (LMI) problem

Tags: matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

I'm trying to find a matrix $P$ such that:
\begin{equation}
x^T P x \leq -1\quad \forall x\neq 0.
\end{equation}

I'm not sure if I can use Schur's complement, which states that:
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
Q(x) & S(X)\\
S(x)^T & R(X)
\end{array}
\right] \succ0
\end{equation}
with $Q(x) = Q(x)^T$, $R(x) = R(x)^T$, $S(x)$ affine in $x$, is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}
R(x) \succ 0 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad Q(x) -  S(x) R^{-1} S(x) \succ 0.
\end{equation}
The reason being that I do *not* want $P \succ 0$. (This would be nonsensical, because then $0\leq x^T P x$ and $x^T P x\leq -1\quad \forall x \neq 0$.)

Any hints?

Comment: There is no matrix $P$ such that $$x^T P x \leq -1\qquad \forall x \neq 0_n$$Did you mean the following? $$x^T P x \leq -x^T x$$

Comment: Ah you're right! No, I meant what I wrote... $x^T P x \leq -1$. Thanks, I'll need to rethink what I'm doing. :)